# Avoid infinite loop in custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created the following custom hook to simplify the usage of timeouts inside my application:

```
export const useTimer = () => {
  const [timer, setTimerObject] = useState<ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> | null>(null)
  
  //Function to set a new timer. If a timer is already present it is
  //canceled and substituted (useEffect)
  function setTimer(callback:(...args:any[])=>void,ms:number){
    setTimerObject(setTimeout(callback,ms))
  }

  //Function to clear the timer (if there's one)
  function clearTimer(){
    if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    setTimerObject(null);
  }

  //shouldComponentUpdate: delete previous timer if a new timer is issued
  //work also as componentWillUnmount
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (timer) clearTimeout(timer)
    }
  }, [timer])

  return ({
    setTimer,
    clearTimer
  })
}
```

However, when I call it inside a useEffect statement, since I have to put timer inside the "dependencies" of the useEffect method, it generates an infinite loop. This is a behaviour I expect somehow, since setting the state will cause the component to "reload" and, as a consequence, useEffect is triggered again (causing the infinite loop). However, by searching online I couldn't find a way to avoid this behavior inside my Hook. For code clarity I want my hook to behaves similarly to useHistory hook. There is a way to edit my hook to avoid infinite loops? (Goal: avoid timer instance being change at every setState)

Here is how the hook is called:

```
const timer = useTimer();

 useEffect(() => {
    if (showError===null) { //Just a random condition to
      setShowError("My error");
      timer.setTimer(() => setShowError(null), 2000)
    }
  }, [timer, showError])
```

Comment: Possible solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67316769/custom-hook-immutable-usestate-to-store-functions-and-avoid-infinite-loop