# Custom hook: immutable useState to store functions and avoid infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**Can the useState hook be used to store an immutable object containing functions to update another state in a custom hook?**

I have a custom Hook that I use to simplify the usage of Timeouts inside my app:

```
export const useTimer = () => {
  const [timer, setTimerObject] = useState<NodeJS.Timeout | null>(null)
  
  //Function to set a new timer. If a timer is already present it is
  //canceled and substituted (useEffect)
  function setTimer(callback:(...args:any[])=>void,ms:number){
    setTimerObject(setTimeout(callback,ms))
  }

  //Function to clear the timer (if there's one)
  function clearTimer(){
    setTimerObject(null);
  }

  //shouldComponentUpdate: delete previous timer if a new timer is issued
  //work also as componentWillUnmount
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (timer) clearTimeout(timer)
    }
  }, [timer])

  return ({
    setTimer,
    clearTimer
  })
}
```

Since I return an object at the end of the hook, every time I set a new timer in a useEffect hook, it starts an infinite loop.

```
const timer = useTimer();

 useEffect(() => {
    if (showError===null) { //Just a random condition to
      setShowError("My error");
      timer.setTimer(() => setShowError(null), 2000) //INFINITE LOOP
    }
  }, [timer, showError])
```

To avoid re-renders at every set state I modified my hook to use a fixed state that contains the functions to update the timer. I didn't use two useCallback() hooks because, if my custom hook returns an object containing the two callbacks, the callback address remains the same, but the object pointing at the callbacks will change at every setState call, generating an infinite loop. However, by using an immutable state Hook, the object reference doesn't change, allowing my custom hook to avoid infinite loops. **Does this approach causes problems that might lead to unexpected behavior of my code, or there is a react hook that satisfies this specific use case?**

```
export const useTimer = () => {
  const [timer, setTimerObject] = useState<NodeJS.Timeout | null>(null);
  //HERE THE IMMUTABLE STATE OBJECT
  const [functions] = useState({
    setTimer : (callback:(...args:any[])=>void,ms:number)=>{
      setTimerObject(setTimeout(callback,ms))
    },
    clearTimer : ()=>{
      setTimerObject(null)
    }
  });
  
  //shouldComponentUpdate: delete previous timer if a new timer is issued
  //work also as componentWillUnmount
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (timer) clearTimeout(timer)
    }
  }, [timer])


  return functions;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
const useTimer = () => { 
    const ref = useRef({ 
      setTimer: function setTimer(callback:(...args:any[])=>void,ms:number){ 
        setTimerObject(setTimeout(callback,ms)) 
      },
      clearTimer: function clearTimer(){ 
        setTimerObject(null);
      } 
    }); 
    return ref.current; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ravi. How does it improve the current version/How ref is "better" than state?

Comment: it does not update between renders unless you modify it.